# Name for maximum size of common neighborhoods between all the pairs of vertices?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

I'm curious if there's a specific term for the following parameter:

Given a graph $G = (V,E)$, i am looking for

$$ \ell(G) := \max_{u,v\in V}|N(u)\cap N(v)|$$

I know that if we look into edges this is the book number of the graph.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By $u,v\in V$ I guess you mean $u,v\in V,\,u\ne v$.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I totally forgot to add it

Comment: In other words, you want the maximum $n$ such that $K_{2,n}$ is a subgraph of $G$.

Comment: can you give or link to the definition of book number of a graph?

Comment: In this article, the definition I was referring to (edge case) is given as 'booksize' https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S019566980400037X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quantity $|N(u) \cap N(v)|$ is referred to as the *codegree* of $u$ and $v$, and so the parameter in the question is the *maximum codegree* of $G$. [Here](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0963548318000032) is an article with an example of this usage.

The codegree is a somewhat unfortunate term, because it is *also* used for a related but different concept for hypergraphs. (In a $k$-uniform hypergraph, the codegree of a set of $k-1$ vertices is the number of edges containing all $k-1$ of them; for graph, this notion of codegree would reduce to the ordinary degree.) There is not really any ambiguity, since the context of the kind of graph you're considering is enough to decide which "codegree" you mean. However, it makes searching for results related to "maximum codegree" a bit challenging.